# CakePHP route '/*' breaking access to subfolders

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I'm just starting with CakePHP and I have a question.

The idea is to have URLs like this:

**domain.tld/some-title-of-a-page**

...and it should open "page" controller with "show" action and some-title-of-a-page as a parameter. What I did in routes.php is:

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'page', 'action' => 'show'));
```

The problem is that I'm unable to read my /css/layout.css file, because it's being parsed as a page with such a title by CakePHP. So what's the recipe for this cake?

**Edit**: Wrong location. The CSS folder should be in app/webroot, not in the web root of the host.

Comment: What's the location of `css/layout.css`?

Comment: It's in the root folder, together with the request collector (index.php).